# Highcharts multiple series remove reserved space

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I've been trying to find a way to do this properly, but as far as I understand it's not possible as of now. Hoping that someone might prove me wrong.

**Some background:**

I'm trying to plot a timeline to keep track of tickets in Jira. No worries getting the data in and drawing each item on separate rows since highcharts is pretty much doing this for me.

**A bit more advanced:**

Going a little further to enhance the viewing experience I would like to group the different items based on something (in my case a single component in Jira), give items in the same group the same color so that the viewer can see that some thing might be related. 
Even this is really simple to do by using multiple series together with categories.

**The problem:**

So when doing the grouping using categories and multiple series (one item/series) the plotting is starting to behave weird.

It seems like each one of the categories (axes) is **reserving space for each series**, even if one category might only have a single item in it. 
This creates way too much whitespace, forcing the items to get really narrow.

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8rtxdaqf/)

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/modules/xrange.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'xrange'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts X-range'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
        reversed: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            y: 0
        }]
    },{
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            y: 1
        },]
    },{
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            y: 2
        },]
    },{
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            y: 1
        },]
    },{
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            y: 1
        },]
    },{
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            y: 2
        },]
    }]

});
```

**What I want:**

Instead of creating a lot of whitespace I want either the width of each item to be relative to the space available in the group, **or** if the group axes themselves could adjust their width according to items inside (and all items is the same width).

I've found a few similar questions, but not a proper solution. 
In [this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7573) github issue the solution is to set grouping to false, but by doing that items in the same category will overlap instead of having their own row.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such behavior is not supported in Highcharts by default, but I created some experimental workaround. We can change the sizes and positions of the points based on calculated values:

```
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var series = this.series,
                categoryWidth = this.yAxis[0].toPixels(2) - this.yAxis[0].toPixels(1),
                pointWidth,
                rectEl,
                y,
                levels = [];

            Highcharts.each(series, function(s) {
                if (!levels[s.yData[0]]) {
                    levels[s.yData[0]] = [s.index]
                } else {
                    levels[s.yData[0]].push(s.index)
                }
            });

            Highcharts.each(levels, function(level) {
                if (level.length > 1) {
                    pointWidth = categoryWidth / level.length;
                    y = series[level[0]].points[0].shapeArgs.y;

                    Highcharts.each(level, function(index) {
                        rectEl = series[index].points[0].graphic.element.children[0];

                        rectEl.setAttribute('height', pointWidth);
                        rectEl.setAttribute('y', y);
                        y += pointWidth;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y8uqsx5h/

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed to continue my work.